# Install and solve dependencies offline for an old version of a package

Tags: yum

I have to install a package (let's call it *foobar*) on a RHEL 6 server which has some pretty tight constraints:

1. the server cannot access the Internet due to security reasons
2. it lacks quite a lot of packages, e.g. the C compiler is missing
3. the foobar to be installed is not the latest version but a previous one

The biggest problem is solving the dependencies. Because of point #3 I cannot simply run `yumdownloader --resolve foobar-3.1.3-1` on an Internet-connected machine to grab the RPMs, transfer them to the server and then do a localinstall: AFAIK `yum` only works with the latest package versions.

Also, grabbing the code source of the foobar package and compiling it is not an option because of point #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer might interest other people, here's how I solved the problem after constraint #3 was relaxed.

I did a minimal installation of RHEL 6 on another machine.  Then I simulated an install of foobar via `yum`, got the list of dependencies, and wrote a script to have `yumdownloader` fetch all the packages.  Finally I packaged the RPMs into a local repo and transferred it to the server.  All that was left to do after that is to run `yum install foobar` on the server.